# How to handle a button click when the button moves and the 'mouseup' is not fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an input box and a button. When the user edits the input text and clicks the button, these events happen:

1. button - `mousedown`
2. input - `change`
3. input - `focusout`
4. button - `mouseup` [doesn't happen]
5. button - `click` [doesn't happen]

http://jsfiddle.net/W2MMb/

Cause: at the input `change` event, a div element containing a warning message is inserted into the DOM above the button, causing the button to move. Therefore the `mouseup` event doesn't happen on the button and no click is registered.

Restrictions: I can't handle the button `mouseup` or `mousedown` individually - it's a 3rd party button and event.

What's the best solution to handling this situation?

Comment: very good. well done . claps for you. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the input `keypress` event instead of the `change` event, but this would have the downside of having to run potentially complex code every time the user presses a key. It could be throttled etc, but that seems kind of overkill.

Handling the `mousedown` on the button would be a bit horrible because the user expects things to happen on `mouseup`.